# How can I create 1500 contacts for my units tests without hitting CPU limit?

Tags: unit-test, governorlimits, failing-tests, loop, cpulimit

I am creating a script that gets run every quarter that checks for any paid status in `campaignMember` objects that has `contactId` attached, and update the status to unpaid and create a `campaignMember` object with each `contactId` for the next quarter. My unit tests run successfully with 200 records, but I can't get it to run with more than that. I would like to make sure that I am testing with at least 1500 records in the end.

This test setup method gets CPU limit error when I set the `numberOfUserToCreate` to more than 200 or so.

```
@testSetup static void setupCotacts() {

List<Contact> con = new List<Contact>();
for(Integer i = 0; i < numberOfUserToCreate; i++) {
        con.add(new Contact(
            FirstName= 'abc'+i,
            LastName= 'Smith' + i,
            MailingCity= 'Seattle',
            MailingCountryCode= 'US',
            MailingPostalCode= '23688',
            MailingStreet= '123 street '+ i + 'th ave',
            MiddleName= 'j',
            Personal_Email__c= 'abc' + i +'@gmail.com',
            Preferred_First_Name__c= 'abc'+ i,
            Preferred_Last_Name__c= 'Smith' + i,
            Preferred_Middle_Name__c= 'j',   
        ));
    }
    insert con;
    System.debug('Contacts : ' + con.size());

  }
```

Comment: It is impossible to do more than just guess without knowing the state of your org. You could have long running `Process Builder` flows, inefficient `Apex Triggers`, etc.

Comment: I guess I would ask why you need to do this; when operating against 1500 objects one is inclined to use a batch class and you can simply test against the batch execute's scope size

Comment: @cropredy if my script needs to process 1500 contact records, shouldn't I have 1500 records created before testing my script even if I used batch to query 200 at a time in my script? I'm new to apex, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: if your script is a batch apex, then for 1500 recs, there will be 2 + n  transactions - (1) start() that queries - no real reason to worry about limits unless you have more than 50million; (2) execute() one Txn per 200 recs; (3) finish() - unusual to have limits issues here. So, you merely need to test that an execute() can successfully process 200 records if you are worried about exceeding limits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few days ago, I came to know that we can use `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` in methods annotated with `@TestSetup`. What this means is that we  can do 3x governor limits in a test method.

**Example**: By default only 10000 DML records are supported per transaction but in the below example, I am able to insert total of 30000 DML records.

```
@isTest
public class ClassA_TEST {

    @TestSetup
    static void makeData(){
        Test.startTest();
        insertTasks(10000);
        Test.stopTest();
    }

    @isTest
    private static void scenarioA(){
        insertTasks(10000);

        Test.startTest();
        insertTasks(10000);
        Test.stopTest();

        Integer noOfRecords = [SELECT Id FROM Task].size();

        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, noOfRecords);
    }

    private static void insertTasks(Integer noOfRecords){
        List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
        for (Integer i =0 ; i< noOfRecords; i++) {
            taskList.add(new Task());
        }
        insert taskList;
    }

}
```

Comment: I was able to successfully create 1500 records for contact objects! Appreciate your precise instruction!

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a CSV , upload it in static resource and load it in test content using test.loadData as

```
List<sObject> ls = Test.loadData(Contact.sObjectType, 'myResource');
```

Src: [Loading Test Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_load_data.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response! I will try that, and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I created a csv file with 1500 contact records, loaded data from SF ui, and called Test.loadData, and I got 'System.SObjectException: common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded' error on the line. Plz assist. Thank you!